# Limiting Function: Composition of Sine Curves

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Define $f_1(x) = \sin(x)$.  For each $k \geq 1$, define $f_{k+1}(x) = (f_k \circ f_1)(x)$.

Are the properties of the limiting function (if it exists) well-known?  That is, as $n$ tends to infinity, how does $f_n$ behave?

Anything you can think of to help me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just found your question. Perhaps [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4131716) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

$f_2(x) =$ sin$($sin$(x))$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is just sin$(x)$ on the open interval $(-1, 1)$. $f_2$ is monotonically increasing, with values $f_2(-1) \approx -0.8414$ and, of course, $f_2(1) \approx 0.8414$.

If we repeat for $f_3$, we get $f_3$ has values between sin $(-0.8414) \gt -0.8414$, and sin$(0.8414) < 0.8414$.

It's clear that whenever $m > n$, we have $Im f_m \subset Im f_n$. But the "peaks" of the function remain at $\{\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n : n \in  \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Also, since $0$ is [an attractive fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29#Attractive_fixed_points) of the function sin$(x)$, we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} Im f_n = \{0\}$. Thus, **your sequence of functions converges to the 0 function everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.**

Visually, at each iteration, the "peaks" get lowered, and they get arbitrarily close to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Note: Studying the behaviour of an arbitrary real number under repeated iterations of the sine function also gives pointwise convergence to the 0 function, perhaps with less clutter.

Comment: I do believe that your comment that 0 is an attractive fixed point assumes the consequent...  I had in mind a proof by induction, using something along the lines of what you showed concerning the images.  Thanks though!

Comment: @Eppo Yes, I just used the fact without proof, but considering $\sin x < x$ for all $x \in (0, \pi$), and the iteration stabilizes at $\sin x = x$, which yields $x = 0$ makes it quite obvious I think.